# Minimum GRANTs needed by mysqldump for dumping a full schema? (TRIGGERs are missing!!)

Tags: database, mysql, database-backups, sql-grant

I have a MySQL user called *dump* with the following perms:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dump'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ...
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON `mysql`.* TO 'dump'@'%'
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON `myschema`.* TO 'dump'@'%'
```

I want to dump all data (included triggers and procedures) using the *dump* user. I call mysqldump in the following way:

```
mysqldump -u dump -p --routines --triggers --quote-names --opt \
    --add-drop-database --databases myschema > myschema.sql
```

Everything is OK with the dumped file except for the **triggers, they are missing**!!

The triggers are dumped correctly if I try mysqldump with *root* MySQL user:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --routines --triggers --quote-names --opt \
    --add-drop-database --databases myschema > myschema.sql
```

So, I guess it is a perms issue... what are the **extra grants my *dump* MySQL user needs for doing the full dump correctly?**

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Assuming by full dump you also mean the `VIEW`s and the `EVENT`s, you would need:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dump'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ...;
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON `mysql`.* TO 'dump'@'%';
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `myschema`.* TO 'dump'@'%';
```

and if you have `VIEW`s that execute a function, then unfortunately you also need `EXECUTE`.

My own problem is: why do I need `SELECT` if I only want to make a no-data dump?

Comment: For 5.5 and above, you actually don't need TRIGGER privilege to dump trigger code.

Comment: I'm using 5.5 and needed the TRIGGER privilege to dump the trigger code.

Comment: In my case it appears I also need `LOCK TABLES` on the database I am trying to dump itself ... using `5.5.49-MariaDB`

Comment: Regarding @0xC0000022L's comment, locking tables or not is optional for mysqldump, depending on your mysqldump parameters (relevant parameters are `--opt`, `--lock-tables`, `--lock-all-tables`, `--single-transaction` and the respective `--skip-*` variants.

Answer (score 8):

I found the extra GRANT I needed!!

```
  GRANT TRIGGER ON `myschema`.* TO 'dump'@'%'
```

Here you have the reference on the official doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger

> The TRIGGER privilege enables trigger operations. You must have this privilege for a table to create, drop, or execute triggers for that table.

Comment: The name is actually TRIGGER, not TRIGGERS

Comment: Even though this may an answer to the author problem, it does not answer the question: "what are the minimum GRANT requirements to do a full dump".   For one: EVENT and SHOW VIEW are missing.

Comment: For 5.5 and above, you actually don't need `TRIGGER` privilege to dump trigger code.

Comment: I use 5.5 and I actually needed it

Answer (score 1):

I found, that sometime if VIEW DEFINER user does not exist, dump fails.

Change it, as described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707173/5215544)

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, solved my problem. I had specified definer as `person`  instead of `person@localhost`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535229/jannes) answer, when using mysqldump with **--tab** option (produces a tab-separated text file for each dumped table), your MySQL user **must be granted** the `FILE` privilege as well:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'dump'@'%';
```

Official docs reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab

Mentioned in this section:

> This option should be used only when mysqldump is run on the same
>   machine as the mysqld server. Because the server creates *.txt files
>   in the directory that you specify, the directory must be writable by
>   the server and the MySQL account that you use must have the FILE
>   privilege. Because mysqldump creates *.sql in the same directory, it
>   must be writable by your system login account.