# Error (1142) SELECT command denied on session_variables table with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

When I try to run `mysqldump -u dump -p myschema > dumpfile.sql` I get this error message:

`mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'gtid\_mode'': SELECT command denied to user 'dump'@'localhost' for table 'session_variables' (1142)`

I found [something](http://blog.teamextension.com/mysqldump-couldnt-execute-select-gtid_mode-unknown-system-variable-gtid_mode-1193-1246) about adding `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` for a similar error. But I'm not running the MySQL 5.6 version of `mysqldump` on an older MySQL database. However, when I try it, I get a new, yet similar, error:

`mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ndbinfo\_version'': SELECT command denied to user 'dump'@'localhost' for table 'session_variables' (1142)`

I'm not sure why the user needs access to the session_variables table, which I presume is `information_schema.SESSION_VARIABLES`, since [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658996/minimum-grants-needed-by-mysqldump-for-dumping-a-full-schema-triggers-are-miss) said that the following permissions were sufficient.​

**Grants for dump@localhost**

```
 GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dump'@'localhost'
 GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON mysql.* TO 'dump'@'localhost'
 GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON myschema.* TO  'dump'@'localhost'
```

What's going on and how do I make mysqldump work?

Here's some of my system info

**MySQL Version**

Server version: 5.7.8-rc MySQL Community Server (GPL)

**mysqldump version**

Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.8-rc, for Linux (x86_64)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is a result of mysql server upgrade.
Run

```
# mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
# systemctl restart mysqld
```

Comment: I think you're right, but I didn't run this code. I noticed the other week that there were patches for the mysql packages. I upgrade six packages to `5.7.9-1.el7` and that cleared up the issue, specifically `mysql-community-client`, `mysql-community-common`, `mysql-community-libs`, `mysql-community-libs-compat`, `mysql-community-release`, and `mysql-community-server`. I'm not sure why that was happening, but I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: If your local mysql root user doesn't have a password, run `mysql_upgrade -u root --force`

Comment: This operation will upgrade columns if needed. I have numerous datetime columns and have lots of "TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME columns of old format have been upgraded to the new format." warnings.