# Grant user access to session variables

Tags: mysql

I recently updated my MySQL to 5.7, whenever I try to mysqldump a table that a user has all permissions on I get the error:

`mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'gtid\_mode'': SELECT command denied to user 'testuser'@'localhost' for table 'session_variables' (1142)`

If I try to dump as root, it works fine.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Then you have not set the user up correctly

Comment: Try reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error (1142) SELECT command denied on session\_variables table with mysqldump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270703/error-1142-select-command-denied-on-session-variables-table-with-mysqldump)

Comment: @BK435 correct, only permission for that one table.. what other permissions should the user have?

Comment: @Shadow i've already done what that answer says

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit the question and tell us what you have done so far!