# which mysql Privileges should I be using for these users?

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

I am creating two users, one is only for `mysqldump` to backup my database, another one is to check `mysql` connection and `galera cluster` status.

I read the `privileges` and set my `backup user` to have the `privileges` of `lock tables` by following this post http://bencane.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-read-only-backup-user-for-mysqldump/

as for to check my connections and cluster status, I gave the user `privileges` of `usage`

Are these two `privileges` the best for what I want to do too? or I should give me other `privileges`?

Thanks for any advices

Comment: Backup user also needs `SELECT` permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privileges required for mysqldump are answered in this previous Stack Overflow post: [Minimum GRANTs needed by mysqldump for dumping a full schema? (TRIGGERs are missing!!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658996/minimum-grants-needed-by-mysqldump-for-dumping-a-full-schema-triggers-are-miss)

Since you said you're using Galera Cluster, you might also need to do an SST from time to time using Percona XtraBackup. The privileges required by XtraBackup are different. See https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/innobackupex/privileges.html